# Shuffle a deck of card with equal likely to be 52 permutations

Tags: algorithm, random, data-structures

I have reading cracking the coding interview book where I have found the below solution for this problem

```
void shuffleArrayiteratively(int[] cards) {
  for (int i= 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      int k = rand(0, i); 
      int temp= cards[k]; cards[k] = cards[i];
      cards[i] = temp;
  }
}
```

In the above code, we are getting random numbers 0 -> i and then swap i with random number but my question is for loop will get a random number in below fashions

```
ramdon = 0 - 1
random = 0 - 2
random = 0 - 3
...
...
random = 0 - 51
```

so 0 have 52 chances to swap with another number and 51 have only one chance. Could someone help me understand why this solution has to be equally likely of 52!

Comment: Here's a good explanation: https://emctackett.medium.com/fisher-yates-shuffle-randomly-shuffle-a-list-in-place-30a05b05a9cb